# Save windows state in DWM

Tags: dwm

I would like to be able to save state of windows opened in all the tags on system halt/logout. Not necessarily with their whole history, just the fact that there was terminal under third tag and browser under fourth tag (for example).

How do I do that in DWM, is there any patch I could use?

**Edit**: I am aware of the philosophy behind DWM and that this probably would be possible by default (e.g. without patches). This is just something I would like to add to my configuration of DWM.

Comment: No. That's not how dwm is designed to work... Just add rules to your `config.h`.

Comment: Yes: it is suckless *and* dynamic... Just use rules if you want the same outcome.

Comment: Check this patch: https://dwm.suckless.org/patches/restoreafterrestart/

Answer (score 5):

dwm isn't designed to save the state of your session; that is typically something that a more full-<strike>bloated</strike>blown desktop environment would do.

Instead, you can write rules in your `config.h` for applications that you would like to start with consistent tags.

To use the examples you mention, a browser and a terminal:

```
static const Rule rules[] = {
    /* class      instance    title       tags mask     isfloating   monitor */
   { "Vimprobable", NULL,       NULL,       1 << 1,       False,       -1 },
   { "urxvtc",      NULL,       NULL,       0 << 1,       False,       -1 },
...
```

This will start a browser in tag 2, and a terminal in tag 1.

You could also add keybinds to simplify launching these applications:

```
/* commands */
static const char   *newtermcmd[] = { "urxvtc", "-title", "newterm", NULL };
static const char   *browsercmd[] = { "vimprobable", "%s", NULL };
...

static Key keys[] = {
    /* modifier                     key        function        argument */
    { 0,                            XK_Menu,   spawn,          {.v = dmenucmd } },
    { MODKEY|ShiftMask,             XK_Return, spawn,          {.v = newtermcmd } },
    { ControlMask|Mod1Mask,         XK_b,      spawn,          {.v = browsercmd } },
...
```

When you start dwm, you can then hit your keybinds and have those applications assigned their respective tags. If you wanted to further develop on this concept, you could write a shell script that opened all of the applications that you require and bind that to a key sequence:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# autostart apps

tabbed -d >/tmp/tabbed.xid; vimprobable2 -e $(</tmp/tabbed.xid) &
urxvtc -title "mutt" -e mutt &
$HOME/bin/shux &
```

As long as there are rules for each of the individual applications, they will be assigned the correct tags; you just assign a key sequence for the shell script:

```
 { ControlMask|Mod1Mask,         XK_a,      spawn,          SHCMD("$HOME/bin/autostart") },
```